# Mock a JavaScript object in production code

Tags: javascript, proxy, mocking

I want to mock a JavaScript object in production code so it can be configured to do nothing. The object is quite complex, and has many properties including nested properties along with functions. Accessing any property should not result in a TypeError, and should have no side effects. Running any function name should be a noop. Counter example:

```
// Naive attempt at resetting the object so it does nothing:
let client = {};

// This will produce a type error:
client.some.nested.prop.here = 10;

// This will produce a type error:
console.log(client.some.nested.prop.here);

// This will also produce a type error:
client.someFunction();
```

What I have tried so far is using a proxy handler:

```js
const clientHandler = {
  set: () => true,
  get: () => {
    return new Proxy(() => {}, clientHandler);
  },
  has: () => true,
  apply: () => {
    console.log('Noop function, mock client used instead.');
  },
};

let client = new Proxy({}, clientHandler);

// No type error, code continues working.
client.some.nested.prop.here = 10;

// No type error, code continues working.
console.log(client.some.other.nested.prop);

// Also no type error, 
client.does.not.exist.someFunction();
```

This does work pretty well. So what I am looking for is whether there is a simpler way to do this, or another more idiomatic approach, or really just any approach that might have different pros and cons to the above. Also any improvements to the above approach would be interesting to consider.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to mock somehting something that is in Production, to be used in Dev ? Or you want to Mock something that will be used in production ?

Comment: Good question. I want to mock something while it is running in production. If I wanted to mock something in dev I would reach for one of the many tools already out there used in testing contexts.